# Google Map isn't loading - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to make an application with Google Map, however, it seems I'm missing out something.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row header">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>{{map}}</ui-gmap-google-map>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('mapApp', [
  'ngRoute'
]).config(['locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    key: 'key',
    v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
});
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    //make magic
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
    });
});
```

and I have added style:

```
.angular-google-map-container {
  height: 400px; }
```

The output doesn't seem to parse the expression well, so I only receive `{{map}}`.

I have lost entire day, trying to figure this one out.. it is probably something 'small' I have missed. Please note, that under 'key' there is a legit API key.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to declare a dependency on the `uiGmapgoogle-maps` module, so replace

```
angular.module('mapApp', [
  'ngRoute'
])
```

with

```
angular.module('mapApp', [
  'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
  'ngRoute'
])
```

There are a few typo issues in the provided example, once they are are fixed too, the map should be loaded as excepted

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('mapApp', [
  'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
  'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  //$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
}])
.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    //key: '',
    v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
})
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
    });
});
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container {
  height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.0.1/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.3.2/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header">
     <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>{{map}}</ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Put the $scope.map outside the promise in controller.  With the current set up you should get an eror - "angular-google-maps: a center or bounds property is required".
>
> ---

```
app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
  $scope.map = {center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
});
```

A plunkr that works - [here - provide a API KEY](http://plnkr.co/edit/wUk74JzI53ljOcjvwaQb?p=preview)